# SQL result from delimited list

Tags: sql, delimiter, denormalization

The column 'serial' contains multiple values separated by colon ':' . It is a delimiter list (separated by :)
I'm using 'where' clause and 'like' operator to retrieve my required serial number and I want to show only that particular serial number in the result column.

my sample table :

```
serial      |name  | description
--------------------------------
123:234:456 |Raj   | Temporary
111:222:333 |Kumar | Permanent
```

my sample code :

```
select serial,name from table
where serial like '%234%'
```

my current result :

```
serial      | name
------------------
123:234:456 | Raj
```

Expected result :

```
serial  | name
--------------
234     | Raj
```

Comment: `select 234 serial, name from table
where concat(':',serial,':') like '%:234:%'`

Comment: For you current expectation you can simply use `select 234,name from table
where serial like '%234%'`. But what if you passed only '23'. What is your expectation then?

Comment: You already asked the exact same question a few minutes before, why deleting and reposting it ? If you want to show the value you pass to `LIKE`, just select it. Again, why do you expect `LIKE` to return only the matching part ?

Comment: You have a nasty table design here, as you know. There are ways to write queries to work around it, but they are RDBMS-specific.  Do you use [tag:postgresql], [tag:mysql], [tag:sql-server], or what? Please [edit] your question to add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0):

use this snippets:

```
declare @cond varchar(10)
set @cond='123'
select @cond as serial,name 
FROM table where serial like '%'+@cond+'%'
```